# I need to compare 2 values and then use some bool functions to return true/false (depends on comparison)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to practice my C++ "skills" (not so good till now)..

So the question is:
The exercise im working on asks me to use 2 boolean functions in my class (1 of them as a friend) to compare 2 values for 2 different objects returned from this function:

```
float Client::maxDeposit()
{
    float max=0;

    for (int w=0; w<5; w++)
    {
        if (deposits[w] > max)
        {
            max = deposits[w];
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "Max funds in a single account: " << max << endl;

    return max;
}
```

These boolean functions have to return "true" if the first client has more money... So how am i supposed to build this? And why the exercise asks me to use 2 different boolean functions?

Thanks a lot!!

Till now i have:
main.cpp
nothing, im still writing the class

client.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Client
{
    private:

        std::string name;
        int deposits[5];

    public:

        void readData();
        void printData();

        float sumOfDeposits();
        float maxDeposit();

        bool mCompDep();

        friend bool fCompDep();

};
```

client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Client::readData()
{
    cout << "Give me your name and your surname please:" << endl;
    cin >> name; 
    cout << "Now inform me about your deposits in your 5 different accounts:" << endl;

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        cin >> deposits[x];
    }

    cout << "Thank you!" << endl;
}


float Client::sumOfDeposits()
{
    float sum=0;

    for (int z=0; z<5; z++)
    {
        sum = sum + deposits[z];

        return sum;
    }
}


float Client::maxDeposit()
{
    float max=0;

    for (int w=0; w<5; w++)
    {
        if (deposits[w] > max)
        {
            max = deposits[w];
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "Max funds in a single account: " << max << endl;

    return max;
}


void Client::printData()
{
    cout << "Customer's ID: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Customer's deposits: " << endl;

    for (int y=0; y<5; y++)
    {
        cout << "Account number " << y+1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "Available Fund: " << deposits[y] << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Total available funds: " << sumOfDeposits() << endl;
}


bool Client::mCompDep()
{

}
```

I can compile this so i think its ok till there..

Comment: for clarifications about your homework please ask your instructor. Otherwise please include a [mcve] and show what you already tried

Comment: @user463035818 Sorry for this im new here so i dont know what exactly to post in order to get a response.. Its not homework, its just practice as i said.. So please tell me what else do you need me to post?? Its difficult for me to translate the whole exercise and thats why i didnt.. Thanks!!

Comment: In order to get a positive response, start with what you already agreed to do, take the [tour]. Then read [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Better avoid using floats for currency.

Comment: What do you mean by "These boolean functions" ? You did not show them, did you? You are asking how to make them. What are the required prototypes? How are they going to be used? Is the code which is going to use them among the shown code?

Comment: @Yunnosch I didnt have time to read all this stuff so i tried something quick.. i will fix it sir.. Thank you!!

Comment: If you want positive response don't give the impression that you make helping you harder by reducing your own effort. Don't take shortcuts. Shine your shoes. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Well as i said the exercise im working on asks me to use 2 boolean functions in my class (1 of them as a friend) to compare 2 values for 2 different objects returned from a function.. more specifically: asks me to compare the fund-sum of two clients.. These boolean functions have to return "true" if the first client has more money... Hope this helps.. Sorry for my english too ..they are not so good at all

Comment: I do not see why comparing two floats requires functions. Are you actually talking about overloading operators like `>` and `<` for the class `Client`?

Comment: I guess you know how the required functions are going to be used. If not re-read your material. If yes show and explain it.

Comment: @Yunnosch This is my problem too.. I do not understand why I have to use functions for something so simple .. the exercise says exactly: Write the functions: ........ 2 functions -1 member and 1 friendly - which will compare the total amount of 2 customer deposits and return true if the first customer participating in the comparison has a higher deposit amount than the second

Comment: Read up on operator overloading, I bet that whatever tutorial you find on that will give you the needed basics and an understanding of where this assignments leads.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you very much sir. I will check some tutorials and come back to inform you if i did well. Have a nice day!